# How to correctly use classes on separate files

Tags: python, class

This is a bit of a hard question to explain, but I am creating a chess AI program where I have a main menu class on one python file and a chessboard file on another. I'm using the Pygame module and I want to be able to continuously switch between the chessboard and the main menu.

The Main Menu has a button to go to chessboard, and chessboard has a button to take me to main menu.

**The problem**
I am currently importing both classes into one another which is giving me a circular import error. I have made methods that imports the classes: [image: openMainMenu method in BoardClass][image: openChessboard method in mainMenuClass]

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: `pygame.quit()` in both classes look strange. Maybe you should modify code to run all code using only one window created with `pygame.init()` (without closing window).

Comment: maybe you shouldn't use `Chessboard` directly in `Menu` and `Menu directly in `Chessboard` but send it as parameter `c = Chessboard(screen) ; m = Menu(screen) ; c.menu = m ; c.chessboard = c` But it would need to create `screen` only once and not use `pygame.quit()`